# Bootstrap, working with offsets in the grid

Tags: asp.net, layout, webforms, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to get the layout of my site right, but whatever I try I cant get the effect I want. Since this is hard to explain Ill add a picture of what I want:

[image]

Hopefully that makes sense.
Here is the code Im using to try and achieve this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2">
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#ff6a00">

        LEFT DIV <br /><br /><br />

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#0094ff">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderMid" runat="server">
        THIS IS THE MIDDLE
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#00ff21">

        RIGHT DIV <br /><br /><br />

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I cant really get it to work, the offset doesnt work the way I think it will and I cant find any answers online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the class container the right way, this class only serves to put a max-width ~1000px

Try this:

```
<div>HEADER</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">LEFT</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">CENTER</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">RIGHT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```